# Google map with multiple markers and location buttons to change center point

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Does anyone know the best way to build a google map with buttons outside of a google map that changes the center point of the map? My company has 3 offices and I would like to be able to click a location to center on that marker. Any help would be much appreciated.

See link for an example:

[Link to screen shot >](http://www.freshegg.com/assets/img/capture.jpg)

Comment: Can you show us some code? It should be very easy.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have defined, initialized and have a reference for Google Maps (in global scope) you can do something like this:

```
document.getElementById('button').onClick = function(){
    map.setCenter(latlngofoffice);
}
```

Comment: Hmm still have issues. Can't get it to work. Here is my code http://jsfiddle.net/P5SXh/

Comment: I want to have the buttons open info windows with custom content for each. Sorry I'm quite new to this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I ended up using [this map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map2.html). Only thing is how do I center the map when you click a location. Can anyone help?